# Binding to Input Properties of Child Component within Router Outlet

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to bind a parent component input *element* value to a child component property. The wrinkle is that the child component is nested within the parent via router-outlet. It seems like the best approach is to use a shared service between the parent and child component as demonstrated [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).

Here's my testing implementation:

**Parent component**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }   from '@angular/router';
import { ThreadsService }   from './threads.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'threads',
    templateUrl: 'threads.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['threads.component.css'],
    providers: [ ThreadsService ]
})


export class ThreadsComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router,
    private threadsService: ThreadsService){}

    emit(value: string) {
        let emission = value;
        this.threadsService.emissionReceived(emission);

    }

}
```

**Parent template**

```
<div class="col-sm-9 threads">
    <div class="threads">
        <div class="thread-container">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li [class.active]="router.url == '/featured'">
                    <a routerLink="/featured">Featured</a>
                </li>
                <li [class.active]="router.url == '/new'">
                    <a routerLink="/new">New</a>
                </li>
                <li [class.active]="router.url == '/trending'">
                     <a routerLink="/trending">Trending</a>
                </li>
                <div class="col-sm-3 search-div">
                    <input #threadsearch (keyup.enter)="emit(threadsearch.value)" type="text" class="form-control  search-box" placeholder="Search topics...">
                </div>
            </ul>
            <!--Child component in here-->          
            <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Child component:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ThreadsService } from './threads.service'
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'featured-threads',
    template: `
        <div class="featured">
        <thread [threads]="threads" [emission]="emission"></thread>
        </div>`, 
    providers: [ ThreadsService ]
})

export class FeaturedThreadsComponent {
    subscription: Subscription;
    emission = '';

    constructor(private threadsService: ThreadsService) { 
        this.subscription = threadsService.searchResults$.subscribe(
            emission => {
                this.emission = emission;
                console.log(emission)
            }
        )

    ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();

    }
}
```

I can log `emission` to console from the parent component and from the shared service, but not from this child component. As you can, see the child component has a child of its own, a template in which `emission` will eventually be rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Günther is completely right in his comment:

> "you get an instance per provider. If you provide it on two components an instance will be created for each instance of these components. If you provide it only on the parent, then the child gets the instance of the parent (or any ancestor) injected. Therefore provide it only once on the component that contains the router-outlet (for one of its ancestors). At the top of the tree (root injector) is AppModule. When no provider is found on any ancestor component the root injector is consulted"

Either you provide your service in your `ngModule`:

```
providers: [ ThreadsService ]
```

and therefore remove the providers from your child and parent.

OR you delete the provider from your child-component.

Here is a plunker with your code, where `providers` is set only in the parent:

### [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QqeF5BAaHtouXYYBdJnH?p=preview)

When looking at the console, you can see that the data is now emitted to child as well.

Finally some excerpts from [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html):

> When a component at the bottom requests a dependency, Angular tries to satisfy that dependency with a provider registered in that component's own injector. If the component's injector lacks the provider, it passes the request up to its parent component's injector. If that injector can't satisfy the request, it passes it along to its parent component's injector. The requests keep bubbling up until we find an injector that can handle the request or run out of component ancestors. If we run out of ancestors, Angular throws an error.
>
> ... Suppose we configured the root injector (marked as A) with providers for Car, Engine and Tires. We create a child component (B) that defines its own providers for Car and Engine This child is the parent of another component (C) that defines its own provider for Car.
>
> Behind the scenes each component sets up its own injector with one or more providers defined for that component itself.

Comment: Ha! I have been puzzling over why this continues to be discussed when I didn't have ThreadsService in the providers array of my child. It turns out I did and didn't realize it. My apologies, guys. I knew it wasn't supposed to be there, so I assumed it wasn't! Accepting your answer because it clearly pointed out that the array was present in my child.

Comment: :D No worries, it's a known fact that one gets blind, when it comes to your own code, we've all been there :D

Comment: Not sure if this can be answered concisely enough for comments, but I have a follow-up question on the behavior of this example. If I log the emissions to console from the service like this, `this.searchResultsSource.subscribe(emission => console.log(emission))`, something strange happens. Here is the [log](https://gyazo.com/09e037127a1237d36df95de73e086b8d). The first search logs nothing. The second, the value in the search field. The third logs the value twice, the fourth three times and so on... Any idea why?

Comment: Uhmm... not sure... where are you doing this logging?

Comment: Within the threads.service method `emmisionReceived()`.     `emissionReceived(value: string) {
        this.searchResultsSource.next(value);
        this.searchResultsSource.subscribe(emission => console.log(emission))
    }`

Answer (score 2):

first of all

```
providers: [ ThreadsService ]
```

all your code is creating new instance for `Child component` as well as new one for `Parent` this will cause harm to your code. Coz service must be singleton and must be added in `NgModule`

**For example**

```
import { NgModule }           from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }      from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }       from './app.component';

import { ThreadsService }        from './threads.service';

import { FormsModule }        from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,  FormsModule ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [ ThreadsService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service), this `provides the instance of the service that it shares with its children (through the providers metadata array) and injects that instance into itself through its constructor`. The child `also injects the service in its constructor`. My understanding is that you can supply the service in the metadata array of a component as long as you don't intend to inject that component outside of the component tree.

Comment: @J.AdamConnor you get an instance per provider. If you provide it on two components an instance will be created for each instance of these components. If you provide it only on the parent, then the child gets the instance of the parent (or any ancestor) injected. Therefore provide it only once on the component that contains the router-outlet (for one of its ancestors). At the top of the tree (root injector) is `AppModule`. When no provider is found on any ancestor component the root injector is consulted.